# The variance of two running variances

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

Having 2 sets, and only this data for each one, the running variance, the sum, the running mean and the count. How can I get the merged variance of the 2 sets?

EDIT:

The values of the sets are being updated each time with new ocurrences this ocurrences are not being stored.

The values of the sets are not equal.

I need to merge this 2 sets and get the new variance of this merged set.

EDIT 2:

I think that what I need is the pooled variance, am I correct?

In java would be something like this

```java
Double variance = (((firstAggregate.count - 1) * firstAggregate.variance) + ((secondAggregate.count - 1) * secondAggregate.variance)) / ((otherAggregate.count + secondAggregate.count) - 2);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, please add more details to your question

Comment: Done, do you need more information? Im new to statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to merge two sets and compute the variance, it's a time consuming task you can compute the variance for each of them separately, then update the total variance. Updating variance could be done by using an update formula.
[image: updating formula]

$T_1,_m = \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \\$

$S_1,_m =  \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i - \frac{1}{m}*T_1,_m)^2 \\$

The equation discussed at a [pairwise algorithm](https://books.google.com.eg/books?hl=en&lr=&id=UyvvCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA30&dq=related:V25H45TDCXeMOM:scholar.google.com/&ots=V-iheQlZxv&sig=KZLc6TFEHbCqf4EaDwj5p3WpavU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) for computing sample variances paper.

---

### Update

[Parallel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Parallel_algorithm)

Comment: thank you @m-zayan that pairwise algorithm is what in wikipedia is called the parallel algorithm, and is what I need, if you could add it to your answer so it can be more complete :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Parallel_algorithm

Comment: you are welcome, note the edit of the T, T is the sum over all elements in the set not (mean). I have added it, thanks.